# Dimensional Problem with simple coefficient equation

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, dimension

[image]

I am trying to create this function in MATLAB. From a previous question, I have solved for `a` as `agrid2` and `f(a)` as `fx`, whose dimensions are `600*1` and `600*2`- these two vectors are absolutely correct:

```
%calculating gini coefficent 

m = 600; 

for i = 1:m %expanded length of kgrid of ai previously calculated in invarden.m 
    
    mu = sum(agrid2.*fx(m,:));
    gini = sum(fx(m,1)*(fx(m,2))*abs(fx(m,1)-fx(m,2)))./(2*mu); 
        
end
```

However, my code is returning all blank answers.

what did I do wrong? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what the matrices `agrid2` and `fx` are, however `mu` should be computed outside that for loop, since in the formula (1) it is not included in the summation. So, you should first compute `mu`, and then `G`.

Furthermore, from your code it seems that inside the function `abs()` you are considering `f` instead of `a`.

Also, I am pretty sure you need a double for loop, since there are two summations in (1).